# Get list of running Apps on Mac OS X in Bash?

Tags: macos, bash

Is it possible to get the list of running Apps using Bash?

I'm not talking about processes, but the apps in the Dock (and also the ones in the menubar would be nice).

Comment: Perhaps http://apple.stackexchange.com would be a better audience

Comment: Or http://unix.stackexchange.com .

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to get name of (processes where background only is false)'
```

Comment: Wow what is that gem? Applescript?

Comment: The part in single quotes is AppleScript. The `osa` in `osascript` stands for “Open Scripting Architecture”.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to work any more? In MacOS Mojave, it just seems to hang until Ctrl-C is pressed, without displaying anything in the terminal.

Comment: You may need to open System Preferences, go to the Security & Privacy pane, then the Privacy tab, then find Automation in the list and grant permission for Terminal.app to control System Events.app.

Comment: What a beauty. So concise!

Answer (score 0):

Well, `ps -e` lists everything; will that do it?

Comment: Nope, it does also include non-application processes

Comment: You said "I'm nopt just talking about processes, but the apps in the Dock." Perhaps you meant "I'm not talking about processes, but just the apps in the dock?" Yout placement of that one word "just" implies to me that you want *both*; my placement implies *only apps*. Maybe you should edit your question?

Answer (score 0):

The "Apps" in the doc are not really applications, but a directory that's bundled with the application and its resources. Let's look at Safari:

```
$ ps -futyilo | grep Safari
501 57923   280   0  9:56PM ??         6:18.27 /Applications/Safari.app/Contents/MacOS/Safari -psn_0_3679106
```

You could use this to find your *apps*:

```
$ ps -futyilo | grep "\.app/"
```

or maybe:

```
$ ps -futyilo | grep "/Contents/"
```

Answer (score -2):

ps aux is your best friend :)

see here:

http://www.linux.ie/newusers/beginners-linux-guide/ps.php